# conditional regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I've parsing a xml file that sometimes has the value `<avg_cpc>some number</avg_cpc>` sometime don't.

my regex look like this:

```
<is_adult>(.*?)</is_adult>.*?<trademark_probability>(.*?)</trademark_probability>.*?<total_extensions_used>(.*?)</total_extensions_used> **here comes the <avg_cpc>some number</avg_cpc>** .*?</appraisal>
```

how can I make this regex match items that don't have cpc value ?
I've tried `(<avg_cpc>.*?</avg_cpc>)?` without luck.
Thanks !

Comment: If you have an XML file, you should not be using regular expression. Instead, you should be using SimpleXML or DOMDocument : those are made to parse XML.

Comment: Why do you need to do this with a regular expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use a [real XML parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) for PHP, instead of regular expressions. This will make everything much easier, not to mention less error-prone.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I need answers for the regex, thanks tho.

Comment: No you don't, you're just being stubborn. You should really use an XML parser.

Comment: They might be more willing if you gave them at least a bit sample code to work with. As for me, I didn't find XML parsing to be particularly straightforward in any language I tried it in so far (including PowerShell).

Comment: you were right, it's better to use a "real XML parser for PHP"

Answer (score 2):

I would guess it's because you're not escaping your slashes, try this:

```
<is_adult>(.*?)<\/is_adult>.*?<trademark_probability>(.*?)<\/trademark_probability>.*?<total_extensions_used>(.*?)<\/total_extensions_used>(<avg_cpc>.*?<\/avg_cpc>)?.*?<\/appraisal>
```

I would also use [^<]+ instead of .*? if possible.

Comment: That's true only if he happens to be using `/` as the regex delimiter.  The forward slash has no special meaning in the regex itself.  But +1 for suggesting `[^<]*` in place of `.*?`.